# Access array-elements inside JSON-object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I have the following json-object returned via response

[image]

the function

```
 function getUserList() {

$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: "paul rudd",
        movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]
    },
    success: function(response){

        console.log(response); // prints the object


    }
});

}
```

My question is how the **movies-array** are accessed in javascript? I cannot access it via response - if I do i get "undefined" returned.

i.e response.movies

*undefined*

or response.movies[0]

*uncaught typerror cannot read property [0] of undefined*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property of the object appears to be `"movies[]"`, not `"movies"`, for which you can use bracket notation to get the value of

```
console.log(response["movies[]"][0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `response['movies[]']`. Also, you could console log the `response` object and inspect what is inside it

Comment: I get undefined in both cases

Answer (score 2):

in your back end you're returning with bad naming , so

to access that array you've to access it as below `response.["movies[]"]`

see below sample :

```js
response = { "movies[]":  ["1","2","3"] };

console.log(response["movies[]"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

movies is array, use `$.each` or `.forEach()`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    name: "paul rudd",
    movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $.each(response.movies, function(index, value){
      // prints the object
      console.log(value);
    })
  }
});
```